External hard drive not working
I got this error message when I tried to open an external hard drive:

Error mounting/dev/sdb1 at media/(device name)

In another Ask Ubuntu post one answer recommmended to run sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 in terminal. I did this but I still get the same error. I have attached a photo of the output message. Can anyone see what else I might need to do to get this drive working?
The hard drive doesn't work on windows either.


If you are ging to post questions here please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and other help topics. Help is at the bottom of the page. Your HD since it does not work in both OS seems to be dead, you can try to format it.
